# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing an error while i am trying to call the following angularjs method with id and $event as parameter

```
    $scope.gotoLink = function(id, $event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        var currentLocation = $location.hash();

        $timeout(function() {
            $location.hash(id);
            $anchorScroll();
            // reset location to initial value,
            // required to stop modal window auto-closing
            $location.hash(currentLocation);
        });
    };
```

Error is as follows

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.gotoLink (http://upfdev/ui/accounts/xyzcontroller.js:68:41)
    at Parser.functionCall (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10847:21)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19136:17)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12702:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12800:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement. (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19141:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:5095:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (http://upfdev/ui/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:4766:28)**

I am not sure why this error when I have already inject $location. Eagerly awaiting any help..Spent a good time on this finding the issue

Comment: As it says `$location` is undefined in this scope and there is nothing in your code snippet to suggest that it should be defined.

Comment: looks like forgot to inject `$location`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this:

.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', '**$location**',  function($scope, **$location**)